# How to get the values of checkbox on jQuery datatable

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, checkbox, datatables

I cannot get the values of every chekbox on table, I get just values of the page on focus even if I check others checkbox on others page, it doesn't work. I want to get every values checked when I submit the form. This is what I have:

```js
function checkbox() {
  var data = [];
  $('.person_data').each(function() {
    if (this.checked == true) {
      data.push(this.value);
    }
  });
  var str = data.join(', ');
  $.ajax({
    url: 'getcheck',
    method: 'get',
    ContentType: 'json',
    data: {
      check: str
    },
    success: function(response) {}
  });
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="example">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th><input type="checkbox" name="select_all" id="select_all"  value="Tous"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Tous</th>
   <th style="width: 130px;">Module</th>
 </thead>
 <c:choose>
   <c:when test="${fn:length(List)>0}">
   <tbody>
      <c:forEach items="${List}" var="var">
      <tr>
      <td>                       
      <input type="checkbox" class="person_data"    value="${var.id}"/>
       </td>   
       <td><c:out value="${var.module}"></c:out><td>
       </tr>    
       </c:forEach>   
   </tbody>
   </c:when>
 </c:choose>
</table>
```